# Rails: How do self-referential has_many models work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, self-join

So, I'm working on an app where I want to users to be able to group objects in "folders". Basically:

`User has_many :foos`

Foos don't have to be in a folder, but they can be. In that case:

`Folder has_many :foos` and `Foo belongs_to :folder`

Now, I'd like to be able to set up folders so they can be nested. I think this is something like...

`Folder has_many :folders`

I have heard that this kind of self-referential relationship is no big deal, but I don't really get how it works. I haven't been able to figure out how this is supposed to be declared in the model and what columns I need to provide in the database.

Could anyone offer an example? I'd also value any suggestions/heads-up/warnings/lessons learned that you might be able to offer about setting up this kind of relationship in an app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Checkout coreyward's answer to the question here:  [Creating a model that has a tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109303/creating-a-model-that-has-a-tree-structure)

Basically you want to add a "parent_id" field to your folders table and then set up a relationship in your Folder model like this:

```
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Folder"
has_many :folders, :foreign_key => "parent_id"
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain you don't need the `:foreign_key => "parent_id"` on the belongs_to line.  It should only be on the has_many line, yes?

Comment: If you want to name the child relationship something else, e.g. `children_folders` then you need to specify the class_name:  `has_many :children_folders, :foreign_key => "parent_id", :class_name => "Folder"`

Comment: And what about a mix? like :all_folders how could we do?