# Rails: has_many :through association only at one side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I am new to ruby and ruby-on-rails. I need to implement complicated tagging engine:

- each tag could have 0 or more synonyms (yep, just like on SO)
- there should be an *hierarchy* of tags: i.e. there are sub-tags and super-tags. Say, I have three tags: `programming`, `ruby` and `c`. Then, `programming` is a super-tag of both `ruby` and `c`, and when I enter tags for item about ruby, it's not necessary to enter tag `programming`, I can only tag it with `ruby`. When I enter tags, all the super-tags should be added recursively. (actually it's strange I've never seen any tags engine with this feature, I really feel lack of it)
- each user should have its own set of tags, i.e. each `Tag` `belongs_to` `User`. Tags aren't public to anyone, they are private to its owner.

It seems I can't use `acts_as_taggable_on` gem, right? So I have to implement my own one. Actually I have already implemented `Tag` class that supports hierarchy, synonyms and users stuff, it seems to work. But there are a lot of questions how to make something taggable with it.

I am trying to reverse-engineer `acts_as_taggable_on`, it is really complicated for a newbie like me..

So, there are a lot of questions, but I'm going to be more specific now:

Assume I have a class `Item` that I want to be taggable. As far as I understand, I should use `has_many :through` association, both on `Item` and `Tag` side. And therefore create intermediate table with `item_id` and `tag_id` fields.

**BUT**: I want my tagging engine to be universal! So I don't want to add to `Tag` model anything related to `Item`.

**So, the only real question is**: is it generally ok to create `has_many :through` association only on `Item` side?

And secondly, if anyone has some suggestions on the stuff I explained, I'd be happy to see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to swapnilabnave's great answer, I'll explain what you're looking for:

I would recommend breaking up your problem into more modular issues

Your question is whether you can use `has_many :through` for the relation. The answer, as explained, is "yes", but that won't solve the problem in its entirety

---

**Hierarchy Of Tags**

As mentioned, your tags will have "parents" and other items

Although I don't have huge experience with this in Rails, in CakePHP, this will be known as a [tree structure](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html). CakePHP handles this by having 3 columns - `parent_id`, `left`, `right`. These basically allow the app to specifically show the various items in your tree based on which numbers are used in those 3 columns

In your case, I'd recommend putting a `parent_id` column in the `tags` database, which you'll be able to assign a super tag to if required (it seems you only have one super-tag per tag?). You could handle this in your model using the [self-referencing association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) technique that swapnilabnave posted to give the ability to call the `super_tag` like this:

```
@tag.super_tag
```

And important note would be that this would only work if you could only have one `super_tag` per tag. If you wanted an unlimited number of super tags per tag, you'd do this:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sub_tags, class_name: "Tag", :foreign_key => "super_tag_id"

  has_many :tag_super_tags, class_name: "TagSuperTag", :foreign_key => "super_tag_id"
  has_many :super_tags, :through => :tag_super_tags
end

Class TagSuperTag
    belongs_to :tag
    belongs_to :super_tag, :class => "Tag"
end
```

Although I'm not sure if the join model code will work, it will hopefully show you the idea here. This would create a self-referencing join model called TagSuperTag, and allow you to have a table like this:

```
tag_super_tags
id | tag_id | super_tag_id | created_at | updated_at

tags (no need for super_tag_id)
id | user_id | name | etc
```

This will allow you to add as many super tags as you wish to each tag

---

**User Has Many Tags**

Because each user will have many tags, you can just use the standard `has_many` association, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

This means that each tag will have to have a `user_id` column, to act as a `foreign_key`

---

**Tags Are Universal**

Making tags universal (not just for `item`) will require a [`polymorphic association`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), and what seems to be a join model

As swapnilabnave has described, this join model can be accessed by any model which wants to use it to store tags, thus allowing you to associate any model with it. Here's how you could do this:

```
class TaggedItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :tag
end

tagged_items
id | taggable_type | taggable_id | tag_id | created_at | updated_at
```

This will allow you to reference this model from any other, like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tagged_items, :class_name => "TaggedItem", :as => :taggable, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :tags, :through => :tagged_items
end

class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tagged_items, :class_name => "TaggedItem", :as => :taggable, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :tags, :through => :tagged_items
end
```

And the `Tag` model should `has_many :tagged_items`, too:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tagged_items, :class_name => "TaggedItem", :foreign_key => "tag_id", :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you few things that might help some/most of your problem statements.

**there should be an hierarchy of tags**

self referential has_many association can be used 
[Creating a model that has a tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109303/creating-a-model-that-has-a-tree-structure)

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sub_tags, class_name: "Tag", :foreign_key => "super_tag_id"
  belongs_to :super_tag, class_name: "Tag"
end
```

**I want my tagging engine to be universal! So I don't want to add to Tag model anything related to Item**

Tagging should be polymorphic, as its widely applicable as used.

```
class TaggedItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**is it generally ok to create has_many :through association only on Item side?**

I think yes, `has_may through` is the way to go. So your `Item` model may look like

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, as: :taggable, through: :tagged_items
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't familiar with `polymorphic`.