# Rails tag class with hierarchy

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

The feature I am going to be building is a tag menu using the jquery-ui menu widget.  This will be for searching purposed.  I'd like to have them all be objects in the Tag model, but am having a tough time wrapping my head around how to have hierarchy within the model.

For example having nightlife => restaurants => seafood, where all three are tag model objects, with seafoods being a type of restaurant and restaurants being a type of nightlife.

The sample code for the jquery-ui menu widget is hard coded but obviously I would like to create it with .erb, being able to create associations within the Tag model so this way if I was to create a different type of restaurant, say steakhouse, that would be associated properly within the model and within the tag hierarchy.

Not sure exactly how to do this.

Comment: Is this what you're talking about? http://jqueryui.com/menu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to check out the [Ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) for this

or

Although you'd need to clarify your referenced "tag" menu (I presume it's http://jqueryui.com/menu/), I'd tackle the issue like this:

[Creating a model that has a tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109303/creating-a-model-that-has-a-tree-structure)

---

**System**

You are right that JQuery needs to be hard-coded (because it's client-side)

The challenge is getting the data into the JQuery function. To do this, you'll need to render the data from Rails (either from helper -- if static -- or model -- if dynamic), and then append them to the rendered page

```
db -> model -> helper -> view (JS)
```

I'll give you an example of using a model to dynamically populate the data:

---

**Model**

Say you have a `Tag` model, you could use a [self-referencial association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) to create a set of `parents` to your tags. These parents would allow you to define the very top-level of menu, trickling down to the sub-levels:

```
#app/models/tag.rb
Class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Tag"
    has_many :children, through: :parent, foreign_key: "parent_id"

    #Gives hierachy
    scope :parents, -> { where(parent_id: nil} ) 
end
```

This should allow you to load:

```
@tag.parents.children
```

This is untested, so probably needs tweaking a lot

---

**Helper**

The helper will just be able to do this:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def menu_tags
    #This needs fixing to enable hierarchies
    gon.push ({
       tags: Tag.all
    })
end
```

---

**Layout**

Because you're calling Rails data, I'd use a [gem called GON](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript) to output the Tags as JS-readable variables:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= include_gon %> #-> makes gon.tags available to JS


#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
// can call gon.tags & use in JQuery
```