# Relate record with other record of same model by id on Ruby on Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I have a model named Tags where each tag has a name and description but a tag can be the parent for other tags.

I was thinking of adding a parent_id to my model but I want to know if Rails Admin can be configured to relate the child to a parent (another record from same model).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it on: [Creating a model that has a tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109303/creating-a-model-that-has-a-tree-structure)

Thanks to [coreyward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203130/coreyward)
 :)

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :description, :name, :parent_id
    has_many :children, class_name: "Tag", foreign_key: "parent_id"
    belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Tag",primary_key: "id"
end
```